# Civicrm webform for contribution

Tags: webform-civicrm

In the webform > settings > Civicrm > contributions,
can we list the Fixed Contribution Options i.e the list Contribution Label and amount in the web form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Alan says below: No, webform civicrm doesn't make use of the price set or contribution options (which is just a hidden price set) associated with the contribution page it's connected to.

You need to use the "Contribution Amount" field, then on the webform tab change it to a select box (radio) and enter the options you wish

Comment: And to answer the direct question: no. i.e., webform civicrm doesn't make use of the price set or contribution options (which is just a hidden price set) associated with the contribution page it's connected to. So reproducing the options within the webform as Pete sez is what you want.

Comment: thx alan. had made that clearer in the SE chat but have copy/pasted your improvement as it will be helpful to others. thx

Comment: Note: in D8/D9 - webform contribution config is no longer associated with/connected to a contribution page. All config happens within the webform. Use select, select other - style as radio as buttons - use any of the native webform layout options.

Comment: Good point Karin

Comment: The Contribution Amount field has a type of 'Number'. I'm not seeing any options in the UI to change it to a radio, checkbox, or select list? The only options I see are 'range', 'rating', or 'scale'.

Comment: Looks like it is possible to change the field type by editing the YAML, but not sure whether this is legitimate: YAML says the field type is 'select', UI says its 'Number'.

Comment: You can do this now!